# Simple Django Form Validation without Model

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I'm trying to have *inline* validation appear in a Django form with a custom validator:

```
def validate_true(value):
    if value != 'T':
        raise ValidationError('no', code='invalid')

class Test2016(forms.Form):
    CHOICES_1 = [
        ('T', True),
        ('F', False)
    ]
    q1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES_1, widget=forms.RadioSelect, label='1. Do you run or not?', help_text='', validators=[validate_true])
```

If they didn't select `True`, I want it to, right in the form, show that the answer is wrong when they click submit.

This style validation but obviously with a True/Value radio select option instead.

[image: django form validation]

In the Template:

```
<form action="">
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

---

View Code:

```
def compliance_questions_2016(request):
    year = datetime.datetime.now().year
    completed = False
    form = compliance_forms.Test2016(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'year': year,
        'completed': completed,
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'v2/pos/compliance_questions_2016.html', context)
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: It's not running through the validator. Or doesn't seem like it is. Even if i put a `print` statement in there it doesn't do anything. No `ValidationError` is raised with the current code either.

Comment: How are you using this form? Show your view code.

Comment: Added the template code @DanielRoseman. There's no model code.

Comment: No, the view code.

Comment: View code added @DanielRoseman

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `form.is_valid()` anywhere.